# CHtml link in yii is not working for deletion of the record

Tags: yii

Here in my view i am using like this for deletion of record

```
<?php  echo CHtml::link('Delete',"#", array("submit"=>array('delete', 'id'=>$data->id), 'confirm' => 'Are you sure?','class'=>'btn btn-danger icon_delete'));?>
```

if i am pressing the delete button it is generating the alert box then if i click ok no action deletion is perform that means (it is not going to the controller) can any one help

controller

```
 public function actionDelete($id)
 {
 $this->loadModel($id)->delete();
 if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
 $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('view'));
 }
```

Comment: You mention it's not going to the controller - how have you verified it's not going to the controller?  Are you saying that if you run this in Firebug, you see no request being made after you confirm the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

The code for deleting the record is fine only. I think you should check controller, may be you have not defined the action 'delete'. Just check it.

I think you should change the code in the delete action as follow pattern:

```
    $model = Your_modelClass name::model()->findByPk($id);
    $model->delete();
    $this->redirect(array('list'));
```

Here **Your_modelClass name** should be same as the model(or table, from where you want to delete the data). But make sure that you have created model also for your table.

And the 3rd line is optional, You can use it if want to redirect to any page(here list page).

Think it will help.

Comment: no i am not getting any error message but it is not going to the controllers actionDelete() so the record is not deleting

Comment: it should redirect to the controller then only the delete is perform i will paste the controller also please check thanks

Comment: sorry i am getting one error in jquery files that yii generates i have see it later i will display that error here you please check it out Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submitForm' of undefined index:608
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submitForm' of undefined index:608
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submitForm' of undefined index:608
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submitForm' of undefined index:608
(anonymous function) index:608
f.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i